# IDAPython error no module _idaapi

Tags: python, ida

I am trying to install IDA Pro 5.5 on a windows 7 machine. I have installed python 2.5. When starting IDA, i get error msg that init.py failed. While looking inside this file, i found that it is importing _idaapi module, but I cannot find this module anywhere in IDA installation directory. There is a python module named idaapi.py which is also importing _idaapi. I also tried downloading IDAPython separately, but it is not working still. Can anybody suggest something to get rid of this error and make my IDA working properly with IDAPython installed?
Thanks in advance
-Sanjay

Comment: That path for IDA and python? Also please provide python traceback of error. Also try to install python to default dir, like c:\Python25, and check that version of IDAPython exactly match IDA and Python version.

Comment: Yes, I made sure that I am using the right versions. i will try more .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Python interpreter is 32 bit and not a more recently compiled 64 bit version, even if you are running a 64 bit OS. If you need to compile your own you will need the Development kit for your version of IDA. Back in the 5.5 days you had to actually build your own,  but idapython is now included as part of the 6.x versions of today.

Comment: Yes, i am using 32bit version. It seems that IDAPython was there. but to dig more, i installed separately. and it didn't work. will try more.. thanks